# Custom post types sorting admin columns nothing found

Tags: custom-post-types

the code below makes it possible to sort after appointment_start_date column, but if I click on header of the column all appointments disappears (Msg: No Appointments Found).

Here is the code:

```
add_action( 'init',  'custom_post_type' );
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes',  'add_appointment_info_metabox' );
add_filter( 'manage_edit-appointment_columns',  'custom_columns_head', 10 );
add_filter( 'manage_edit-appointment_sortable_columns',  'sortable_columns', 10 );
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'appointment_column_orderby'); 
add_action( 'manage_posts_custom_column',  'custom_columns_display', 10, 2 );
add_action( 'save_post',  'save_appointment_info' );

// Register custom post type
function custom_post_type() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'                  =>   __( 'Appointments', 'upcoming-appointments' ),
        'singular_name'         =>   __( 'Appointment', 'upcoming-appointments' ),
        'add_new_item'          =>   __( 'Add New Appointment', 'upcoming-appointments' ),
        'all_items'             =>   __( 'All Appointments', 'upcoming-appointments' ),
        'edit_item'             =>   __( 'Edit Appointment', 'upcoming-appointments' ),
        'new_item'              =>   __( 'New Appointment', 'upcoming-appointments' ),
        'view_item'             =>   __( 'View Appointment', 'upcoming-appointments' ),
        'not_found'             =>   __( 'No Appointments Found', 'upcoming-appointments' ),
        'not_found_in_trash'    =>   __( 'No Appointments Found in Trash', 'upcoming-appointments' )
    );

    $supports = array(
        'title',
        'editor',
    );

    $args = array(
        'label'         =>   __( 'Appointments', 'upcoming-appointments' ),
        'labels'        =>   $labels,
        'description'   =>   __( 'A list of upcoming appointments', 'upcoming-appointments' ),
        'public'        =>   true,
        'show_in_menu'  =>   true,
        'has_archive'   =>   true,
        'rewrite'       =>   true,
        'supports'      =>   $supports
    );

    register_post_type( 'appointment', $args );
}

// Metaboxes frontend
function render_appointment_info_metabox( $post ) {

    // generate a nonce field
    wp_nonce_field( basename( __FILE__ ), 'appointment-info-nonce' );

    // get previously saved meta values (if any)
    $appointment_start_date = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'appointment-start-date', true );

    // if there is previously saved value then retrieve it, else set it to the current time
    $appointment_start_date = ! empty( $appointment_start_date ) ? $appointment_start_date : time();

    ?>

<label for="appointment-start-date"><?php _e( 'Appointment Start Date:', 'upcoming-appointments' ); ?></label>
        <input class="widefat appointment-date-input" id="appointment-start-date" type="text" name="appointment-start-date" value="<?php echo $appointment_start_date; ?>" required/>

  <?php 
}

// Add metaboxes to cpt
function add_appointment_info_metabox() {
    add_meta_box(
        'appointment-info-metabox',
        __( 'Appointment Info', 'upcoming-appointments' ),
         'render_appointment_info_metabox',
        'appointment',
        'side',
        'core'
    );
}

// Columns to show at the admin page
function custom_columns_head( $defaults ) {
    unset( $defaults['date'] );

    $defaults['appointment_start_date'] = __( 'Start Date', 'upcoming-appointments' );

    return $defaults;
}

// Admin page columns content
function custom_columns_display( $column_name, $post_id ) {
    if ( 'appointment_start_date' == $column_name ) {
        $start_date = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'appointment-start-date', true );
        echo $start_date;
    }
}

// Make columns sortable
function sortable_columns( $columns ) {
    $columns['appointment_start_date'] = 'appointment_start_date';

    return $columns;
}

// Custom sort order for column
function appointment_column_orderby( $query ) {  
       if( ! is_admin() )  
            return;  

        $orderby = $query->get( 'orderby');  

        if( 'appointment_start_date' == $orderby ) {  
            $query->set('meta_key','appointment_start_date'); 
            $query->set('orderby','meta_value_num'); 
        } 

        return $query;
} 

function save_appointment_info( $post_id ) {
    // checking for the 'save' status
    $is_autosave = wp_is_post_autosave( $post_id );
    $is_revision = wp_is_post_revision( $post_id );
    $is_valid_nonce = ( isset( $_POST['appointment-info-nonce'] ) && ( wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['appointment-info-nonce'], basename( __FILE__ ) ) ) ) ? true : false;

    // exit depending on the save status or if the nonce is not valid
    if ( $is_autosave || $is_revision || ! $is_valid_nonce ) {
        return;
    }

    // checking for the values and performing necessary actions
    if ( isset( $_POST['appointment-start-date'] ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'appointment-start-date', $_POST['appointment-start-date']  );
    }
}
```

Default sort after Title:
[image]

Sort after Start Date:
[image]

Comment: please take a screenshot so we can understand the problem a better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you save your data as `appointment-start-date` (hyphens), but in your orderby handler you use `appointment_start_date` (underscores).

They need to match!

```
 $query->set( 'meta_key', 'appointment-start-date' );
```